# How to filter Solr MoreLikeThis Result

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I have query in MoreLikeThis Component, like this :

`/mlt?q=5a25300cc1cb1786198b4571&df=id&fl=*,score&fq=service:2&mlt=true&mlt.fl=pagetext&mlt.mintf=3&mlt.mindf=3&mlt.minwl=3&mlt.maxwl=15&mlt.boost=true&mlt.count=10`

My question is : Can i filter this MoreLikeThis result, something like mlt.fq, where in example mlt.fq=type:vehicle than i'll only get moreLikeThis result from document with type:vehicle only. Like fq for Search Component but instead i use it for MoreLikeThis Component. If i use fq=type:vehicle, its possible that i wont get result because document with id:5a25300cc1cb1786198b4571 have other type(not vehicle).

NB: mlt.fq is not exist. Its just for convenient in my questions.

NB: i cant use mlt.qf for this, because mlt.qf is for something like scoring the similarity, or can i? :)

Answer (score 0):

My Solution : create my own handler and component

In MoreLikeThisComponent, edit search request so it can include params mlt.fq(my new param).

I dont know if its a bad or good solution, but its what i need and it works.